# Написать функцию, которая заменяет нулями все элементы массива, номера которых кратны k

Tags: c, массивы

Дан одномерный целочисленный массив размера N и целое число k. Написать функцию, которая заменяет нулями все элементы массива, номера которых кратны k.

Вот мой код на Си.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int zamena(int k, int N)
{
    int i;
    int a[N];
    for (i=0; i<N; ++i){
    if (i%k==0)
    a[i]=0;
    return a[i];
}
}

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("cls");

    int N, k, i;
    int a[N];
    printf("Введите размер массива: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);


    printf("Введите элементы массива: \n");
    for(i=0; i<N; ++i){
        printf("a[%d]=", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }   

    printf("Ваш массив: \n");
    for (i=0; i<N; ++i){
        printf("a[%d]=%d\t", i, a[i]);
    }

    printf("\Введите число k: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);

    printf("\n\nvivozhy\n");

    for (i=0; i<N; ++i){
        zamena(N, k);
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что оно заменяет на число k(!) почему-то лишь последний элемент массива, в чем моя проблема я не понимаю.

Comment: У вас массив `а` обьявлен два раза. Программа их различает. Простейшее решение - обьявить его один раз в глобальной области.

Comment: Тогда мне нужно в функцию вводить a[i] элемент, я это делаю, моя программа выдает ошибку и вылетает.

Comment: У вас два отдельных массива.. Если хотите "пробросить" массив через параметр - например третьим, то можно так `int zamena(int k, int N, int * a)`, а второе обьявление а из zamena - убрать.

Comment: Все равно крашится на вызове функции, for я пишу вот так:
for (i=0; i<N; ++i){
  zamena(k, N, * a);
  printf("%d\t", a[i]);
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вы усложнили решение, вопрос зачем??
Используйте функцию которая принимает указатель и размер массива,  и там все реализуйте.

Ввод массива я думаю вы пришьете сами)
см. решение

```
#define BUFF_LEN 8

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void foo(int* a, size_t size, int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (i % k == 0) {
            a[i] = 0;
        }
    }

}


int main()
{
    int a[BUFF_LEN] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    int k = 2;

    foo(a, BUFF_LEN, k);

    for (int i = 0; i < BUFF_LEN; ++i) {

        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А можно и еще упростить -- `for (int i = 0; i < size; i += k)
      a[i] = 0;`